# Creating a cube animating their faces

Tags: after-effects

As a beginner, I'm not sure how to create rectangles that form a cube so I can get something like shown below:

[image]

I created angled rectangles in another application and tried to create an idea to show, but I'd really like to use the elements that After Effects provides.

[image]

I would also like to know how to control the quality of the corners of the elements created within After Effects.

[image]

Anyone willing to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Bezier command that will help you a lot.

[image]